# Map array or object to array improvement

Tags: javascript, arrays

Question is simple, I have an object property `content.categories` that may be an array or a single object.

In any case, I'd like to create a new array containing the id/ids.

What I'm doing here is checking if property is an array, otherwise add the object into an array and finally map it.

Is there any way to improve this code? Feels ugly to me but I didn't find a way to make ir shorter.

```js
categoriesIds = Array.isArray(content.categories) 
      ? content.categories?.map((category) => category.id) 
      : [content.categories]?.map((category) => category.id)
```

Comment: if you're already checking for array then don't map on the second case. Also you don't need optional chaining having just checked if it's an array. `categoriesIds = Array.isArray(content.categories) ? content.categories.map((category) => category.id) : [content.categories?.category.id]`

Comment: oh yeah in second case just [content.categories.id]

Comment: similar to what pilchard said.  if it's guaranteed to be a single object in the case it's not an array, just return `content.categories.id`

Comment: you need no `?.`, because you have always an array.

Comment: also you could just concat. `categoriesIds = [].concat(content.categories).map((category) => category.id);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could concat with an empty array and value/items. The result is always a flat array of the first level.

```
categoriesIds = [].concat(content.categories).map(({ id }) => id);
```

Comment: This was the kind of sorcery I was looking for. Thanks!